# Is there a way to add comments to localized strings in Interface Builder?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, localization, internationalization, interface-builder

In code, the `NSLocalizedString` macro lets you give a descriptive comment along with your string, so your translators have the necessary context to write a translation. However, I don't see any way to give an equivalent comment along with the strings in my storyboard. Instead, the xliff file contains notes like this:

`Class = "NSTextFieldCell"; title = "Created"; ObjectID = "1u4-pn-J7a";`

Not very useful. Is there any way for me to provide my translators with better explanations of the purpose/placement of these strings?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There *is* a way to do this. In the **Identity** inspector, under **Document**, there is a section called **Notes**. Text added to this section will be included in the `<note>` section of an item in the xliff file.

[image: Xcode identity inspector]
[image: Text of]

Answer (score -1):

Inside the   section you can also add text= and then whatever you want to tell the translator.

Alternatively, if you end up working out of a text file, you can also add a note above or below the string inside forwarded slashes e.g.

"00_bkm_11"="Bookmark";
/Used to mean save a webpage in the app/

Hope these two help :-)

Comment: Interesting, what do you mean by "inside the section"?

Comment: I mean the comments section of a string